# Aggregation Use Case - group by two different kafka streams and compute average

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am stuck in one use case. I need to calculate the % of the amount spent on entertainment.

In my stream, I get the records having industry codes and amount spent( industry codes are entertainment-based  and nonentertainment based)

e.g> entertainment indusrty codes >                     Industry Code   Amount

```
                                                         157       100

                                                         257        200

                                                         157         300
```

nonentertainment indusrty codes >                     Industry Code   Amount

```
                                                         457       100

                                                          657       200

                                                          457       300
```

So I need to calculate how much %  was spent on entertainment which should be total of entertainment amount / (total of entertainment amount+total of nonentertainment amount)

The solution I am trying: Create Two Ktables One entertainment- group by entertainment code i.e.
157    400 ( 100+300)

```
                                   257    100
```

Nonentertainment another KTable     457      400

```
                                 657      200
```

I have now two KTables but how can I calculate the % ? Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what you exactly tried so far. When you create both tables, do both table have multiple rows (ie, one per code) or did you already "merge" different codes together? If each table contains multiple rows, you need to aggregate all rows together by setting a made up surrogate key (like integer value 0 for all rows):

```java
KStream sumSpendingEntertainment = spendingEntertainment.groupBy((k,v) -> 0)
                                                        .aggregate(...);
KStream sumSpendingAll = spendingAll.groupBy((k,v) -> 0)
                                    .aggregate(...);
```

In the end, you get two `KTable` with a single row; one that contains the overall spending, and one that contains the "entertainment spending" and both KTables would use the same made up surrogate key (the integer 0 in our example).

In a last step, you can join both tables to divide both sums:

```
sumSpendingEntertainment.join(sumSpendingAll,
                              (sumEnt, sumAll) -> sumEnt / sumAll); // this is the `ValueJoiner` expressed as lambda
```